# How would I select all the given employee ID's, even those with no occurrences in another table?

Tags: mysql

I'm practicing getting back up to par on MySQL, and have run into an issue using the Northlight practice database. I'm specifically using this site for my practice: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp

I noticed that Employee Adam West (Employee ID 10) does not have any occurrences in the Orders table. I'm trying to get a list that returns the following:

```
FirstName   LastName    Number of Sales
Nancy       Davolio     29
Andrew      Fuller      20
Janet       Leverling   31
Margaret    Peacock     40
Steven      Buchanan    11
Michael     Suyama      18
Robert      King        14
Laura       Callahan    27
Anne        Dodsworth   6
Adam        West        0
```

However, each time, the bottom row (with Adam West = 0) does not return.

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName, COUNT(Employees.EmployeeID) as "Number of Sales"
FROM Employees
WHERE Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
GROUP BY Orders.EmployeeID
```

I've also tried inserting `LEFT JOIN Orders` in, between the `FROM` line and the `WHERE` line, but to no avail.

Comment: Learn the JOIN syntax, is `FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.col=b.col`, remove the WHERE

Comment: Alright, I did that, and it's now returning Adam West, but giving him "1" under `Number of Sales` (I had previously forgotten the `ON` in the syntax). He should have a value of 0, however.

Comment: W3Schools? Really? Friends don't let friends... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the clause to the `ON` statement when using a `LEFT JOIN`.  Also, since `Orders.EmployeeID` may not exist, you want to `GROUP BY Employees.EmployeeID`.

Try this:

```
SELECT Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName, COUNT(Orders.EmployeeID) as "Number of Sales"
FROM Employees
LEFT JOIN Orders ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
GROUP BY Employees.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

Please understand from the below example:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
EmployeeID INT,
FirstName VARCHAR(30),
LastName VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
orderId INT,
EmployeeID INT
);
```

/*Data for the table employees */

```
INSERT  INTO employees(EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName) VALUES (1,'a','z');
INSERT  INTO employees(EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName) VALUES (2,'b','y');
INSERT  INTO employees(EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName) VALUES (3,'c','x');
```

/*Data for the table orders */

```
INSERT  INTO orders(orderId,EmployeeID) VALUES (101,1);
INSERT  INTO orders(orderId,EmployeeID) VALUES (102,2);
INSERT  INTO orders(orderId,EmployeeID) VALUES (103,1);
INSERT  INTO orders(orderId,EmployeeID) VALUES (104,1);

SELECT Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName, COUNT(orders.EmployeeID) AS "Number of Sales"
FROM Employees LEFT JOIN Orders 
ON(Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID)
GROUP BY Orders.EmployeeID;

FirstName  LastName  Number of Sales  
c          X         0                
a          z         3                
b          Y         1
```

A left join is used here. it will fetch all the rows from left table and the matched entry from the right table. Here c don't have an entry in Orders table.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. here is my solution...

**How many orders has the Batman sold to customers whose names end in a consonant?**

```
SELECT em.EmployeeID, em.LastName, em.FirstName, COUNT(Customers.CustomerID) as  'number of orders'
FROM (SELECT *
FROM Employees
LEFT JOIN Orders ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
WHERE Employees.EmployeeID = 10) as em
LEFT JOIN Customers ON em.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
WHERE Customers.CustomerID is null 
OR (Customers.CustomerName not LIKE '%a'
    AND Customers.CustomerName not LIKE '%e'
    AND Customers.CustomerName not LIKE '%i'
    AND Customers.CustomerName not LIKE '%o'
    AND Customers.CustomerName not LIKE '%u'
    AND Customers.CustomerName not LIKE '%y')
```

RESULT:
EmployeeID  LastName    FirstName   number of orders
10     West     Adam        0